# Logo seen on website is different than StackExchange bar logo

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I noticed that this logo that is seen in the StackExchange site bar (and the favicon):

[image: StackExchange bar logo]

is different from the big one seen on the site:

[image: Big Puzzling logo]

The difference is that there are no borders, less pale colors, and the most prominent, the color at the top-left of the logo is blue in the tiny icon, and green in the big one.

Is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: This is intentional. How would you draw the borders in the tiny logo?

Comment: A really small 1px line could work.

Answer (score 3):

It might be because of the limitation of the size of our monitor. However as I am not an expert, so I am not sure but when you zoom in the window you get this:

[image]

Here clearly, we can see the borders and the same colors.

Comment: He's right.  It appears to be simply the resizing of the icons to fit the schema.